# oplog.rsにsystem系コレクションのオペレーションログを出力させたい。

Tags: mongodb

mongodにてスロークエリを出力することに関して質問させてください。
最近mongodでスロークエリを出力するために,ProfilingLevelを1に引き上げ、system.profileコレクションにスローログを出力するように設定しました。
このスローログをarbiterでも閲覧したいと考え、
(1) system.profileに出力
(2) oplog.rsに(1)のオペレーションログを出力
(3) arbiterが(2)を同期する

という流れを考えたのですが、(2)のoplog.rsに(1)のオペレーションログがうまく出力されません。
もしかして、oplog.rsにはsystem系のコレクションに対するオペレーションログは出力されないのでしょうか。(現状(1)に関しては、system.profileにちゃんと出力されるようになっています)

すみませんがご教授のほどよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> もしかして、oplog.rsにはsystem系のコレクションに対するオペレーションログは出力されないのでしょうか。

*local* DBの全部と*system.profile*だけはレプリケーションしないんです。

src/mongo/db/repl/oplog.cppから

```cpp
bool oplogDisabled(OperationContext* txn,
                   ReplicationCoordinator::Mode replicationMode,
                   const NamespaceString& nss) {
    if (replicationMode == ReplicationCoordinator::modeNone)
        return true;

    if (nss.db() == "local")
        return true;

    if (nss.isSystemDotProfile()) // == "system.profile"
        return true;

    if (!txn->writesAreReplicated())
        return true;

    fassert(28626, txn->recoveryUnit());

    return false;
}
```

なぜならプライマリーのプロファイル結果はセコンダリーのと一致しないべきです。ハードウェア差、ランダムタイミングなどの理由で異なっています

db.setProfilingLevel()を実行したらそのMongoDBノードだけで*system.profile*を適用する仕組みがあるということです。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。確かにハードウェアごとにプロファイル結果は異なりますから、同期しないべきですね。